# Why does jQuery submit screw up this click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, events

I've been using this throughout my code with no issue:

```
// alerts
window.cAlert = function (msg) {
    // insert
align.append("<div id=\"alert\">" + msg + "</div>");
    // object
    alertBody = $("#alert");
    // css values
    alertTop = (wh - alertBody.outerHeight()) / 2;
    alertLeft = (ww - alertBody.outerWidth()) / 2;
    // alert css
    alertBody.css({
        top: alertTop,
        left: alertLeft
    }).transition({
        opacity: 1
    }, 300);
    // delete alert
    $(window).on("click scroll touchstart resize", function (e) {
        alertBody.transition({
            opacity: 0,
            x: -(ww / 2),
            rotate: "-360deg"
        }, 600, function () {
            alertBody.remove();
        });
    });
}
```

But inside my submit function, it doesn't work as expected:

```
  $(document).on("submit", "#twigForm", function (e) {
     // fix
     e.preventDefault();
     // object
     var twigObj = $(this);
     // the file data
     var file = ($("#upload"))[0].files[0];
     // checks
     if(!file) {
         cAlert("You didn't select an image, silly");
     } else if(file.size >= 2097152) {
         cAlert("Filesize cannot exceed 2 MB");
     } else if(file.type !== "image/jpeg" && file.type !== "image/jpg" && file.type !== "image/gif" && file.type !== "image/png") {
         cAlert("Are you sure that's an image?");
     }
});
```

Expected behavior: the alert message should dissapear when the user clicks (anywhere), scrolls, touches, or resizes the window, which it does. However, if the user has made an error in the form a **second** time, the alert message instantly fades out, even though I haven't scrolled/resized/clicked/etc. I didn't even catch what the error read. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Appreciate the edit @Sumurai8, I was cleaning out the crap before submitting the answer, and added the closing brackets incorrectly.

Comment: `align.append("<div id=\"alert\">" + msg + "</div>");` gives me error , what is that ? as well as `wh` ,`ww` variables are undefined . You should proved as jsfiddle exmple

Comment: Align, ww, wh are defined as global variables in the code before this. That's not the issue.

Comment: update this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rxAkZ/

Comment: tried `alertBody.remove(true);` ?

Comment: I updated the fiddle with the variables http://jsfiddle.net/rxAkZ/2/ - using true didn't work. It only allowed one error message. What if the user makes a second mistake?

Comment: Where is that "transition" thing supposed to come from?  It's not a base jQuery API.

Comment: @Pointy transition is transit.js, for doing CSS transitions with jQuery. It's very smooth.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `.one()` instead of `.on()` when setting up the event handler. Your code leaves the handler there on the window, so what I bet is happening is that the "click" on the button is triggering the handler installed by the previous submit, so it immediately starts the countdown to remove the alert.

By using `.one()`, each handler will only run once.

Comment: Partially solved. If you click away the error message, then submit, works lovely. But if you click the submit while the error message is still there, the error message goes but the submit doesn't submit the form. If I try submitting again, the original issue occurs.

Comment: @DanielSchwarz the "submit" function won't submit the form because you've got a call to `e.preventDefault()` in the handler.

Comment: I meant that it doesn't execute any code, only removes the error. I'll be using ajax later, so the e.preventDefault() is necessary.

Comment: @DanielSchwarz it would be much easier to help if there were a working (well, working like your page works) jsfiddle or jsbin.

Comment: @DanielSchwarz [here is a working (I think) jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xC5jL/).  Note that an important change was to declare "alertBody" and some other variables as locals. Also, it empties the "align" element before adding a new message to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Was just creating a fiddle before you did, doh! Thanks, your solution worked flawlessly. The only area I needed to alter though was changing alertBody to var alertBody.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rxAkZ/8/) of your code:

```
 $(window).on("click scroll touchstart resize", function (e) {
        alertBody.transition({
            opacity: 0,
            x: -(ww / 2),
            rotate: "-360deg"
        }, 600, function () {
```

## $(this).remove();

```
        });
    });
```

Instead of the `alertBody.remove`, use `$(this).remove()`. I have fixed some typos in your origional demo and its working as expected